# Ionic 4 Angular Application Mac Address App restart needed after allowing permission

Tags: angular, cordova-plugins, ionic4

Implemented ionic code with required plugin but it gives the message "Please Restart App!".  Without restart app Mac address getting null. After restart getting proper Mac address. How to get Mac address without restart app.

Link refered : https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-get-unique-device-id-other-uids-of-uuid-imei-imsi-iccid-and-mac-using-native-cordova-plugins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write windows.location.reload after permission granted to get valid Mac address. As after permission granted it needs to restart App so in app.component.ts after permission reload the component.